# The usage of where in "let the ship go ashore where she fancied"

Tags: relative-clauses

> Let the ship go ashore where she fancied.

I am confused about  "where" usage in this sentence. I think the use "where" is not concerned with the second clause (she fancied). Please help me with this usage.

Comment: _"...let Aung Thu go where she wanted."_ Do you understand that phrase? The usage of _where_ is the same as in the phrase you quote from Stevenson, which is actually _"...let her go ashore where she fancied."_

Comment: **to fancy**: to have in mind a person, thing, or place, as a choice or preference.     *They let their small child wander at the park where she fancied.*  that is, "where she pleased", "wherever she wanted to go".